# Can't read file more than once in c++

Tags: c++, file

In my assignment i have a problem with reading a file. See the following code segment.

```
    std::string data;
    std::ifstream fileRead;

    fileRead.open("a.txt");

    while (fileRead >> data) 
    {
        long a = fileRead.tellg();
        fileRead.seekg (a+1, ios::beg);

        std::string check;
        //some code here

        while (fileRead >> check)
        {
            //some code here
        }
        fileRead.seekg (a+1, ios::beg);
    }
```

I have to check how many same words are in the file. My logic is, i read a word and keep it in data. Then  i continue reading after that word using fileRead.seekg (a+1, ios::beg); Then i compare each of the words in the file.

After checking whole file i again put my fileobject to next word using this line fileRead.seekg (a+1, ios::beg); But this line is not working. I mean first while loop just work once. Someone please help me out here.

By the way, i am totally new in file operation. So my logic or concept may not be correct in that case tell me what is the right way to do this? But i need to know why first while loop ends just after reading one word?

Comment: I'm curious as to why you use `fileRead.seekg (a+1, ios::beg)` instead of `fileRead.ignore(1)` or `get(1)` which seems a little clearer to me.

Comment: @Rook im totally new in file. So i don't have any idea how fileRead.ignore(1) or get(1) will work in this case.

Comment: Have a read through the docs; there are plenty of online copies ([CPP Reference is one](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_fstream)) and you may find that there are existing functions that will do what you need with less effort than your current ways.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you read file as `while(fileRead >> data)`, the a failure flag is set for the stream object, before exiting the loop. In fact, it is set that is *why* it exits the loop. You need to clear this  *failure* flagas:

```
fileRead.clear(); //clear the failure flag
fileRead.seekg (0, ios::beg);
//now read
```

Comment: It is probably worth distinguishing between the `fail` and `bad` status flags. In the event of `fileRead.bad()` returning true, you might consider closing and re-opening the stream, or terminating the application... if my understanding is correct, `badbit` implies a potentially nonrecoverable error.